# Game development using sprite kit issues in nodes?

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit

when user touch the screen create SKSpriteNode image from mid of y-axis & x-axis is Zero. The SKSpriteNode image reach touched position.It's work fine.when user touch multiple times continually multiple SKSpriteNode image was created but multiple SKSpriteNode images was collide with each other then the angle was change except first image.I need image move one by one without change an angle.

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
      UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];

      CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

    SKSpriteNode * projectile = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Arrow_Ballon"];
    projectile.position = self.player.position;
    projectile.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:projectile.frame.size];
    projectile.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = projectileCategory;
    projectile.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = monsterCategory;
    projectile.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = projectileCategory | monsterCategory;
    projectile.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;

    [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"arrow.wav" waitForCompletion:NO]];

    CGPoint offset = rwSub(location, projectile.position);


    if (offset.x <= 0) return;

    [self addChild:projectile];

    CGPoint direction = rwNormalize(offset);

    CGPoint shootAmount = rwMult(direction, 1000);

    CGPoint realDest = rwAdd(shootAmount, projectile.position);

    float angle = atan2f (location.y - projectile.position.y, location.x - projectile.position.x) ;

    float velocity = 500.0/1.0;
    float realMoveDuration = self.size.width / velocity;
    SKAction * actionangle = [SKAction rotateByAngle:angle duration:0.0];
    SKAction * actionMove = [SKAction moveTo:realDest duration:realMoveDuration];
    SKAction * actionMoveDone = [SKAction removeFromParent];
    [projectile runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[actionangle,actionMove,actionMoveDone]]];
```

}

I don't know how to solve this issues.can anyone know please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you change this:

```
 projectile.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = projectileCategory | monsterCategory;
```

to

```
 projectile.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = monsterCategory;
```